# In Ruby, What are my options in looping through a collection of user objects, @users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a collection of users in a object @users.

In the Ruby language, what are the various ways of looping this collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way would be to use

```
@users.each{|user| 
# do something with user
}
```

Other than that there are the usual index based for loops.

Comment: After `each` ends, `user` will be inaccessible; after a `for` ends, `user` will have the last value that was put into `user`. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
@users.each { |user| do_something(user) }

@users.each do |user| 
  do_one_thing(user)
  do_another
end

for user in @users
  do_something(user)
end
```

The first two are idiomatic. You also have methods like each_with_index if you need an index variable as well.  There are many more, check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

By "collection of users", do you mean you have an array of something representing users? Arrays mix-in the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) module, which gives you lots of nice ways of traversing its contents.

If "collection of users" means you created some object that contains the collection, then by implementing the `each` method and mixing in Enumerable you get all its methods. Your `each` method will have to iterate over successive users in your collection one at a time, one user per call.